# How do i stop the recycle view from clearing text entries?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a recycle view that only consists of text boxes. When you type something into the textbox, scroll down and scroll back up the text will be gone.

I tried updating the data list of the recycle view but when I scroll it just resets it again. I made a seperate program with just the recycle view to try toexperiment.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Builder.load_string('''
<Row>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    itemText: ''

    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText

<Row2>
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    itemText: ''
    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText
    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText2

<RV>:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Row'
    pos: 10,-50
    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
    bar_width: dp(10)
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols:6
        default_size: None, dp(30) 
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(1)
''')


class RV(RecycleView):
    list_items = ListProperty([])
    numRows = 16
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':0},
                     {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':0},
                     {'itemText': '0','paren': self, 'index':2},
                     {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':0},
                     {'itemText': '0','paren': self, 'index':2},
                     {'itemText': '0','paren': self, 'index':2}]
        for x in range(2,32):
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': str(x), 'paren': self, 'index':6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'index': 6}])

    def which_edit(self, *args):
        '''This will print the index of the box which is currently edited'''
        #print args[0].parent.index


class Row(BoxLayout):
    paren = ObjectProperty() #the instance of the rv

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Row, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.paren.list_items.append(self)
        self.ids.CellText.bind(text=self.paren.which_edit)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1

> I tried updating the data list of the recycle view but when I scroll
>   it just resets it again.

### Root Cause

Whatever is typed into the TextInput is not reflected in `self.data`. Due to this, whenever there is a scroll, the TextInput is refreshed from `self.data`.

## Problem 2

Overwrote `index` e.g. `{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'index':0},`

### Explanation

`index` is a reserved attributes for RecycleView. It is used to identify each cell in the columns.

## Solution

### kv file

Update self.data whenever there is any changes to TextInput.

#### Snippets

```
TextInput:
    id:CellText
    text:root.itemText
    on_text:
        app.root.data[root.index]['itemText'] = self.text
```

### Python Script

Replace `index` with `Index`

#### Snippets

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.data = [{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                 {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                 {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2},
                 {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                 {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2},
                 {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2}]
    for x in range(2, 32):
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': str(x), 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
        self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Row>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    itemText: ''

    TextInput:
        id:CellText
        text:root.itemText 
        on_text:
            #root.which_edit(args)
            app.root.data[root.index]['itemText'] = self.text

<RV>:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Row'
    pos: 10,-50

    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
    bar_width: dp(10)

    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols:6
        default_size: None, dp(30) 
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(1)
''')


class Row(RecycleDataViewBehavior, BoxLayout):
    pass
    index = None
    selected = BooleanProperty(False)
    selectable = BooleanProperty(True)

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
        self.index = index
        return super(Row, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        ''' Add selection on touch down '''
        if super(Row, self).on_touch_down(touch):
            return True
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos) and self.selectable:
            return self.parent.select_with_touch(self.index, touch)

    def apply_selection(self, rv, index, is_selected):
        ''' Respond to the selection of items in the view. '''
        self.selected = is_selected
        if is_selected:
            print("selection changed to {0}".format(rv.data[index]))
        else:
            print("selection removed for {0}".format(rv.data[index]))

    def which_edit(self, *args):
        '''This will print the index of the box which is currently edited'''
        print(f'args={args}')


class RV(RecycleView):
    numRows = 16

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                     {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                     {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2},
                     {'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 0},
                     {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2},
                     {'itemText': '0', 'paren': self, 'Index': 2}]
        for x in range(2, 32):
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': str(x), 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "1", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])
            self.data.extend([{'itemText': "0", 'paren': self, 'Index': 6}])


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return RV()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```